# Nesting closure templates within another template

Tags: nested, google-closure, google-closure-templates

I'm sure there should be some way to render another template from within a template so I don't have to copy paste similar looking blocks. I'm just not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
{call .templateName /}
```

Comment: If anyone else finds this topic in the future, here are all the features: http://code.google.com/p/closure-templates/source/browse/trunk/examples/features.soy

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass parameters your can do it this way:

```
{template .teasersblock}
  <div> 
      {call .teaser}
          {param url: 'https://example.com' /}
          {param headline: 'My headline example' /}
      {/call}
  </div>
{/template}
```